# Select one of many groups of array definition

Tags: arrays, variable

I use variable.tex to definite some Array: Name, color, folder

In main.tex:
\input{variable.tex}

In variable.tex: ( not exist begin/end{document}
Each Group includes 3 Array: Name, color, folder

```
%GROUP A
\def\ArrayAnameOne{{“a11”,”a12”..”a19”}}

\def\ArrayAcolorTwo{{“a21”,”a22”..”a29”}}

\def\ArrayAfolderNine{{“a91”,”a92”..”99”}}


%GROUP B
\def\ArrayBnameOne{{“b11”,”b12”..”b19”}}

\def\ArrayBcolorTwo{{“b21”,”b22”..”b29”}}

\def\ArrayBfolderNine{{“b91”,”b92”..”b99”}}


%GROUP C
\def\ArrayCnameOne{{“c11”,”c12”..”c19”}}

\def\ArrayCcolorTwo{{“c21”,”c22”..”c29”}}

\def\ArrayCfolderNine{{“c91”,”c92”..”c99”}}

%GROUP D
\def\ArrayDnameOne{{“d11”,”d12”..”d19”}}

    \def\ArrayDcolorTwo{{“d21”,”d22”..”d29”}}

    \def\ArrayDfolderNine{{“d91”,”d92”..”d99”}}
```

When i want to use all arrays of GROUP A, i muss hide with symbol percent % (ctrl T) > 150 rows of other GROUP: Group B, Group C, GROUP D. 
And it creates many manual error and take time.

So, I need other better solution in variable.tex:

Example:

\SelectGroup{XXX}

Variable Xxx variable used inside =  one of (A, or B, or C, or D)

Please help

Thank in advance

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me. What does "use a group" mean? At this point you are just defining twelve different macros.

Comment: It would be useful to know *how* you want to use this.

Comment: @egreg campa:for each customer,  i need to create some different pdf layout design (image folder, color, name).